# How do you set multiple instance fields from the parameters of a method in one line in JAVA?

Tags: java, parameters, field, instance

So I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Example {
    private String apple;
    private String orange;

    public void setNew(String apple, String orange) {
       //Instead of 
       this.apple = apple;
       this.orange = orange;

       //I once saw a way you could do it in one line like
       this.(apple, orange) = (apple,orange);

       //but this does not compile
   }
```

How can I set apple to apple and orange to orange in one line?

Comment: You can do it in one line, just not in one statement.

Comment: You can, however, set it to the same value in one line by `this.apple = this.orange = apple`.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a C++ or C# program you saw it in?

Comment: *"I once saw a way you could do it in one line"* That wasn't Java code you saw.

Comment: Do you realize that this question took more to type than just doing it in two statements?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate to use fluent interface (aka Builder pattern) like this: `withApple(apple).withOrange(orange);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Java.  You will have to accept using multiple statements.

Comment: maybe he means adding no-arg constructor with will call the two arg constructor with static values? That would be one line :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setNew(String apple, String orange){    
    this.apple = apple; this.orange = orange;
}
```

Comment: ";" means end of a line, so that's not the answer buddy.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but this is the closest thing to what he/she was asking. ";" means end of statement, so this is valid java.

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki Sure it's a valid answer. Question asks for one line, not one statement: *"How can I set apple to apple and orange to orange **in one line**?"* --- `;` certainly doesn't mean end-of-line. It means end-of-statement. There is a big, BIG difference between a line and a statement. In Java, there is no relation between the two, since a line terminator has no meaning, except of the line-comment (`//`).

Comment: I rest my case.

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki You've made no case.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion and every one is entitled to one. I personally consider this kind of answer as wrong. I did not say it's an invalid java (but apparently every reasonable code reviewer would). Perhaps a language barrier cased misundestating regarding meaning of ";", in any case ( made or not made) this answer is wrong! And do not add any value to the discussion.The OP gave an example of what is an expected answer. @shmosel - Would you like to add any more constructive comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

So what I was thinking of was when you have another method that calls the constructor as:

`this(param1, param2);`

Then as the comments have suggested, you do have to individually set the instance fields.